# tablesorter-filter and jquery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, jquery-filter

I am using https://github.com/jbritten/jquery-tablesorter-filter , jquery table sorter plugin, and the jquery table sorter pagination.

when I load the settings in the document load and add the filter it destroys pagination.  I have had this issue with every single table filter plugin I have tried to use.

```
var $table = $('#billing_summary_table')
.on('pagerInitialized pagerComplete', function (e, c) {
    var i, pages = '', t = [],
        cur = c.page + 1,
        start = cur > 1 ? (c.totalPages - cur < 3 ? -3 + (c.totalPages - cur) : -1) : 0,
        end = cur < 3 ? 5 - cur : 2;
    for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (cur + i >= 1 && cur + i < c.totalPages) { t.push( cur + i ); }
    }
    // make sure first and last page are included in the pagination
    if ($.inArray(1, t) === -1) { t.push(1); }
    if ($.inArray(c.totalPages, t) === -1) { t.push(c.totalPages); }
    // sort the list
    t = t.sort(function(a, b){ return a - b; });
    // make links and spacers
    $.each(t, function(j, v){
        pages += '<a href="#" class="' + (v === cur ? 'current' : '') + '">' + v + '</a>';
        pages += j < t.length - 1 && ( t[j+1] - 1 !== v ) ? ' ... ' : ( j >= t.length - 1 ? '' : ' ' );
    });
    $('.pagecount').html(pages);
})
.tablesorter({
    widgets: ['zebra']
})
.tablesorterPager({
    container: $(".pager"),
    size: 3,
    output: 'showing: {startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',
    removeRows: false
})
.tablesorterFilter({
    filterContainer: "#filter",
    filterColumns: [0,1,2,3]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/). The reason is that the pager plugin has an option `removeRows` which is `false` by default, so all tables rows still exist on the page (in the DOM) making filtering easy. So, it should work (untested) with the filter plugin you mentioned.

Also, check out:

- The basic [filter widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html) which adds a filter to each column.
- The filter widget using the [filter_anyMatch](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-any-match.html) option which allows you to add your own input to search all the contents of the table.
- Using the filter widget with [more than one external search input](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-external-inputs.html)
- [A demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ZFZNF/16/) of the [quicksearch plugin](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) used in conjunction with the pager plugin.

Comment: for the demo of the quicksearch plugin.. which version of tablesorter and which paginator did you use?

Comment: That demo always uses the latest version of tablesorter & pager from my fork.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put filter into `.tablesorter()` function

```
.tablesorter({
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    filter_columnFilters: true,//If u want a single filter for each column
    filter_external: '#filter'
}}
```

You have more info here: [Tablesorter external input](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-external-inputs.html)

I think it will work for you, I was implementing it just today.